# Do I have to enter the public IP into the HOME_NET variable?

Tags: suricata

Do I have to enter the public IP of `eth0` as `HOME_NET` in the `suricata.yaml`?

```
vars:
  # more specific is better for alert accuracy and performance
  address-groups:
    HOME_NET: "[192.168.0.0/16,10.0.0.0/8,172.16.0.0/12]"
```

My understanding is that only private addresses belong in the variable `HOME_NET`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$HOME_NET` is supposed to list the IP addresses of your protected hosts/networks. It doesn't matter if these addresses are private or public.